# Pulling player records

Tags: sql, mysql

I was able to pull the records I wanted but I have a feeling it could be written better for these particular MySQL query strings.

```
SELECT ID,XAxis,YAxis,Player,Castle,Alliance FROM SC75
WHERE Snap = (SELECT MAX(SavedSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE Server = 75)
AND hex(Player) IN (hex('Vandiel'))
UNION
SELECT SC.ID,XAxis,YAxis,SC.Player,Castle,Alliance FROM SC75 AS SC
INNER JOIN AltFiller AS AF ON hex(AF.Player) IN (hex('Vandiel'))
WHERE SC.Player = AF.Alts
AND Snap = (SELECT MAX(SavedSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE Server = 75)
ORDER BY Player,Castle
```

Comment: This doesn't look too awkward given the scarce information provided, but for starters - why do you have a table named ``SC75``? Does that mean that you also have tables ``SC74``, ``SC73`` and so forth? Does the ``75`` in ``SC75`` relate to ``Server = 75``?

If you posted the schema, I could have some comments.

Comment: Pretty much and I came across other Database knowledgable person and was pointed out a few flaw but improved, will be posting in a few what was pointed out :)

Comment: Okay, but a broken schema leads to broken queries. This query could potentially be much simpler if you used a better schema. In other words, asking about whether a query "looks right" will usually wind up becoming a discussion about the schema it is using. So you should start out getting the schema right (feel free to post it in another review question here).

Comment: See below for changes I've made.

Comment: Sorry. I think you're answering a question I didn't ask :) When i write "database schema", I refer to the table layout.

Comment: Explain why you use `hex(stuff) IN hex('Vandiel')` instead of just `stuff = 'Vandiel'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts to the `UNION` have too much in common.  I believe this query is equivalent to yours.

```
SELECT ID, XAxis, YAxis, Player, Castle, Alliance
    FROM SC75
    WHERE
        Snap = (SELECT MAX(SavedSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE Server = 75)
            AND
        (
            (hex(Player) IN (hex('Vandiel'))
                OR
            Player IN
            (
                SELECT AF.Alts
                    FROM AltFiller AS AF
                    WHERE hex(AF.Player) IN (hex('Vandiel'))
            )
        )
    ORDER BY Player, Castle;
```